# Add IBAN check to widget validation

Tags: google-app-maker

For an employee questionnaire I would like to add an IBAN check to a textbox widget. Is it possible to add a library like https://github.com/arhs/iban.js as an external resource in App Maker? How do I have to implement a validation method once the library has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add any external library. If library is available via CDN (Content Delivery Network) you can just add URL in `Application Settings -> External Resources -> JavaScript URLs`
 otherwise you can upload the js file as app resource (`Settings -> Resources`) and use resource's URL instead.

The library will help you to validate input on client:

```javascript
// onValidate event of input widget:
if (!IBAN.isValid(newValue)) {
  return 'Please, provide valid account number';
}
```

But it will not help you with server side validation... So, end user can in theory compromise your system through dev console. You can try to copy/paste library's code to server script and make extra validation in `onBeforeCreate` and `onBeforeSave` model's events but most likely it will require some additional tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using Regex to validate the IBAN - you won't need to worry about pulling in external JS then. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656264/iban-regex-design?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) may be useful. With this regex, you can validate the string server side, which is more secure. [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) has more information on validating RegEx in Javascript.