# Regex for IBAN mask

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract this text "NL dd ABNA ddddddddd" from collection of strings and I need to create expression that would match the third title:

```
IBAN NL 91ABNA0417463300
IBAN NL91ABNA0417164300
Iban: NL 69 ABNA 402032566
```

To date, I use this regex pattern for extraction:

```
NL\s?\d{2}\s?[A-Z]{4}0\s?\d{9}$
```

Which matches the first two examples, but not the third.

To reproduce this issue, see this example:
[https://regex101.com/r/zGDXa2/1.](https://regex101.com/r/zGDXa2/1)

How can I treat it?

Comment: Please put a [mcve] **in the question**.

Comment: Why don't you remove all the white spaces? That would make the regex easier. In python you can do `sentence = ' hello  apple'`, `sentence.replace(" ", "")`

Comment: I would also uppercase the strings, that way you avoid yourself including lowercase letters in the regex. Just use ` sentence.upper()`

Comment: try this      NL.*\d{9}$           https://regex101.com/r/f9JVP2/4

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: did you search SO? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656264 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23471591 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iban+regex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?i)(?:(?<=IBAN(?:[:\s]\s|\s[:\s]))NL\s?\d{2}\s?[A-Z]{4}[0 ]\s?\d{9,10})|(?:(?<=IBAN[:\s])NL\s?\d{2}\s?[A-Z]{4}[0 ]\s?\d{9,10})
```

**demo:**

https://regex101.com/r/zGDXa2/11

If you work in python you can remove the `(?:i)` and replace it by a flag `re.I` or `re.IGNORECASE`

**Tested on:**

```
Uw BTW nummer NL80
 IBAN NL 11abna0317164300asdfasf234
iBAN NL21ABNA0417134300 22
Iban: NL 29 ABNA 401422366f sdf
IBAN :NL 39 ABNA 0822416395s
IBAN:NL 39 ABNA 0822416395s
```

**Extracts:**

```
NL 11abna0317164300
NL21ABNA0417134300
NL 29 ABNA 401422366
NL 39 ABNA 0822416395
NL 39 ABNA 0822416395
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your regex101 demo is, there is an extra character in your regex after `$` so remove that and change `0` to `[0 ]` and this fixes all and starts matching your third line too. The correct regex becomes,

```
NL\s?\d{2}\s?[A-Z]{4}[0 ]\s?\d{9}$
```

**[Check your updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/zGDXa2/3)**

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove all spaces and uppercase the rest, Like this:

```
iban = NL 91ABNA0417463300
iban.replace(" ", "")
iban.upper()
```

And then your regex would be:

```
NL\d{2}ABNA(\d{10}|\d{9})
```

It works in https://regex101.com/r/zGDXa2/1

Answer (score 1):

It's not what you want, but works.

IBAN has a strict format, so it's better to normalize it, and next just cut part, because everything will match regexp, as an example:

**CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# I'm not sure, that alphabet is correct, A-Z, 0-9
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"


def normalize(string):
    stage1 = "".join(IBAN.split()).upper()
    stage2 = ''
    for l in stage1:
        if l in alphabet:
            stage2 = stage2 + l

    return stage2.split('IBAN')[1]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    IBAN_LIST = ['IBAN NL 91ABNA0417463300', 'IBAN NL91ABNA0417164300', 'Iban: NL 69 ABNA 402032566']

    for IBAN in IBAN_LIST:
        IBAN_normalized = normalize(IBAN)
        print(IBAN_normalized[2:4], IBAN_normalized[8:])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
91 0417463300
91 0417164300
69 402032566
```

It's not a regexp, but should work faster, but if you know how to normalize better, please, help with it.

You can see source code [here](https://github.com/caa06d9c/Examples/blob/master/Python/basic/regexp/iban/run.py).